# Xamarin - Binding command inside stacklayout datatemplate not working

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, command

Trying to fire a command inside a stacklayout with itemssource. I wonder why the NavigateToProductListViewShopTappedCommand is not getting fired.

Tried multiple command approaches:

1)

```
Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyShopsListViewModel}}, Path=NavigateToProductListViewShopTappedCommand}"
```

2. 

```
Command="{Binding BindingContext.NavigateToProductListViewShopTappedCommand, Source={x:Reference Page}}"
```

3. 

```
Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.NavigateToProductListViewShopTappedCommand, Source={x:Reference Page}}"
```

None are not working

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:BoerPlaza.Controls.Shop"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BoerPlaza.ViewModels"
             xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:BoerPlaza.Behaviors"
             x:Class="BoerPlaza.Views.Shop.MyShopsPage"
             x:Name="Page"
             Title="Mijn winkels">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout Margin="{StaticResource margin-side-std}"
                         Padding="{StaticResource padding-top-bottom-std}"
                         BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Shops}">
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <controls:ShopCardTemplateView Shop="{Binding .}"
                                                       ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ShopCardTemplateView}">
                            <controls:ShopCardTemplateView.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                                      Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyShopsListViewModel}}, Path=NavigateToProductListViewShopTappedCommand}"
                                                      CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                                                      <!--Command="{Binding BindingContext.NavigateToProductListViewShopTappedCommand, Source={x:Reference Page}}"-->
                                </TapGestureRecognizer>
                            </controls:ShopCardTemplateView.GestureRecognizers>
                        </controls:ShopCardTemplateView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Code behind

```
public partial class MyShopsPage : ContentPage
    {
        private readonly MyShopsListViewModel _viewModel;

        public MyShopsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = _viewModel = new MyShopsListViewModel(App.ShopDataStore, App.DialogService);
            _viewModel.LoadShopsOnUserIdCommand.Execute("B22698B8-42A2-4115-9631-1C2D1E2AC5F7");
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            _viewModel.OnAppearing();
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(UserId), nameof(UserId))]
public class MyShopsListViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string _userId;
    private ObservableCollection<ShopDbViewModel> _shops;
    private readonly IShopDataStore _shopDataStore;
    private readonly IDialogService _dialogService;

    public ObservableCollection<ShopDbViewModel> Shops
    {
        get
        {
            return _shops;
        }
        set
        {
            _shops = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Shops));
        }
    }

    public void OnAppearing()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
    }
    public ICommand LoadShopsOnUserIdCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand NavigateToProductListViewShopTappedCommand { get; set; }

    public MyShopsListViewModel(IShopDataStore shopDataStore, IDialogService dialogService)
    {
        this._shopDataStore = shopDataStore;
        this._dialogService = dialogService;

        Shops = new ObservableCollection<ShopDbViewModel>();

        LoadShopsOnUserIdCommand = new Command<string>(async (string userId) => await ExecuteLoadShopsOnUserId(userId));
        NavigateToProductListViewShopTappedCommand = new Command<ShopDbViewModel>(async (ShopDbViewModel shop) => await ExecuteNavigateToProductListViewShopTappedCommandAsync(shop));

    }

    private async Task ExecuteNavigateToProductListViewShopTappedCommandAsync(ShopDbViewModel shop)
    {
        if (shop == null)
            return;

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(ProductsPage)}?{nameof(MyProductsListViewModel.ShopId)}={shop.Id}");
    }

    public string UserId
    {
        get
        {
            return _userId;
        }
        set
        {
            _userId = value;
            LoadShopsOnUserIdCommand.Execute(value);
        }
    }

    private async Task ExecuteLoadShopsOnUserId(string userId)
    {
        var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;

        if (current == NetworkAccess.Internet)
        {
            try
            {
                Shops.Clear();
                var shops = await _shopDataStore.GetShopOnUserIdAsync(userId);
                foreach(var shop in shops)
                {
                    Shops.Add(shop);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await _dialogService.ShowDialog(ex.Message, "An error has occurred", "OK");
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await _dialogService.ShowDialog("No active internet connection", "Connection error", "OK");
            IsBusy = false;
        }
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that will help more people who has similar issue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:ffimage="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
             xmlns:customcontrols="clr-namespace:BoerPlaza.Controls"
             x:Class="BoerPlaza.Controls.Shop.ShopCardTemplateView">
    <ContentView.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ShopCardTemplateView">
            <!-- Card Header -->
            <!-- for displaying products and categories on homepage -->
            <StackLayout Spacing="1"
                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         Margin="{StaticResource margin-card}">
                <!-- On click - shows the product detail view page -->
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <!-- Image frame -->
                <Frame  BackgroundColor="{StaticResource image-box-color}"
                        CornerRadius="0"
                        HasShadow="False"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        HeightRequest="100">
                    <!-- Product Image -->
```

....

As you can see this is the control template I'm using for the MyShopsPage. This is a shop card. Inside this shop card I already had an StackLayout.GestureRecognizers. Somehow when I was clicking on the control template, I was actually clicking on this.

I always thought everything flows from top to bottom in events, but this seems different. Something that is on top on something else does not mean anything in xaml.

Answer (score 0):

If you define the ICommand in the ViewModel directly , you could set the binding path like following

```
Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.NavigateToProductListViewShopTappedCommand, Source={x:Reference Page}}"
```

Comment: Could you share your sample so that I can test it on my side ?

Comment: https://github.com/TweakStories/BoerPlaza. The project can be downloaded from here. It's for school and my first project, so can be a bit messy :P. Thank you

Comment: Make sure that you had remove all personal information like password, account and personal IP address